# devise treats username as email and asks for @

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise authentication gem in Rails with mongoid, all the latest versions(Rails 4.2,mongoid 5,devise 3.5,ruby 2.2.3).

I have added :database_authenticatable module to my model(which is Researcher) and have done all the instructions in [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address) page to sign in with username, I also have validatable and confirmable.

My problem is that devise validates username as email so when I put for example user it says "you forgot to add the @ sign to the email", Here is a screenshot:
[image: the error message]

this is my `rake routes`:

```
                        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
                          root GET    /                                       researchers#new
        new_researcher_session GET    /researchers/sign_in(.:format)          researchers/sessions#new
            researcher_session POST   /researchers/sign_in(.:format)          researchers/sessions#create
    destroy_researcher_session DELETE /researchers/sign_out(.:format)         researchers/sessions#destroy
cancel_researcher_registration GET    /researchers/cancel(.:format)           researchers#cancel
       researcher_registration POST   /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#create
   new_researcher_registration GET    /researchers/sign_up(.:format)          researchers#new
  edit_researcher_registration GET    /researchers/edit(.:format)             researchers#edit
                               PATCH  /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#update
                               PUT    /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#update
                               DELETE /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#destroy
       researcher_confirmation POST   /researchers/confirmation(.:format)     researchers/confirmations#create
   new_researcher_confirmation GET    /researchers/confirmation/new(.:format) researchers/confirmations#new
                               GET    /researchers/confirmation(.:format)     researchers/confirmations#show
                   researchers GET    /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#index
                               POST   /researchers(.:format)                  researchers#create
                new_researcher GET    /researchers/new(.:format)              researchers#new
               edit_researcher GET    /researchers/:id/edit(.:format)         researchers#edit
                    researcher GET    /researchers/:id(.:format)              researchers#show
                               PATCH  /researchers/:id(.:format)              researchers#update
                               PUT    /researchers/:id(.:format)              researchers#update
                               DELETE /researchers/:id(.:format)              researchers#destroy
```

the screenshot is /researchers/sign_up page.

and this is my project hierarchy, controllers:

```
    tree app/controllers
app/controllers
├── application_controller.rb
├── concerns
├── researchers
│   ├── confirmations_controller.rb
│   └── sessions_controller.rb
└── researchers_controller.rb
```

views:

```
   app/views
├── application
├── layouts
│   ├── application.html.erb
│   ├── mailer.html.erb
│   └── mailer.text.erb
├── researchers
│   ├── confirmations
│   │   └── new.html.erb
│   ├── new.html.erb
│   ├── sessions
│   │   └── new.html.erb
│   └── show.html.erb
└── researchers_confirmation
    ├── confirmation_instructions.html.erb
    └── confirmation_instructions.text.erb
```

I'm ready to add any information necessary.

### PS

I only have devise right now, this problem occurred even when I didn't have confirmable and validatable .

As for the message in the screenshot, I have ar.yml for arabic locale, I set default locale to english for the purpose of the screenshot but seems devise didn't listen to me, the message in the screenshot is the translation of the english text "Please add the "@" sign to the email address because "user" lacks the "@" sign".

By the way I know there is reg_exp for email in devise initializer but I'm afraid If changed that , devise won't validate email field as email.

Comment: Could you share your form view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the view of the form. I think that the warning message is fired by the **browser** and not by your js validation.

Check if you wrongly set `input type=email` also for username field.

Comment: Man that's really the issue, I copied devise views and didn't realize this, thanks, I always get stuck on simple problems like this xD

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)